# how many parameters does it take to remember one picture

Tags: python, validation, parameters, keras, classification

so I am using Keras(backend Tensorflow) and trying to find a net to solve the cifar10 classification.
I made a simple net. I get an accuracy of almost 100%, which in my opinion means that it is devinitly overfitting. 
My network has 337,834 trainable Parameters and i have 35000 Training images with size (32,32,3)(RGB).
My Question is how many Parameters does it take to "remember" one Image.
Is one Parameter enough to remember one image or would it rather take 32*32*3, so one parameter for each value of a picture?

Another Question I have is: Is my Validation done correctly, using the validation split?

Thank you

```
import keras
from keras.layers import *

#Preprocessing__________________________________________________________________________________________________________

traindata = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,  validation_split=0.7)

input = traindata.flow_from_directory('Cifar10/cifar/train',
                                      target_size=(32, 32), color_mode='rgb', batch_size=50,
                                      subset='validation')
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________



#Building Model_________________________________________________________________________________________________________

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Deconv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, input_shape=(32, 32, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Deconv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________


#Training_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

model.fit_generator(input, epochs=100, validation_data=input,
                    callbacks=[keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(write_images=True, log_dir='./'),
                               keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('temp/Cifar10 .h5', save_best_only=True)],
                    validation_steps=100)
```

## Summary Output

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 32, 32, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 32, 32, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 32768)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                327690    
=================================================================
Total params: 337,834
Trainable params: 337,834
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: I just realised I made a realy stupid error. I used Deconv2D insteaed of Conv2D.

Comment: Questions are the same though.